# Does same conditional probability distribution imply same unconditional probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, independence

Consider the real-valued random variables $X,Y,Z,W$ defined on the same probability space and taking value respectively in $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{Z}, \mathcal{W}$.

Assume that
$$
X| Z=z,W=w \overset{d}{\sim} Y| Z=z,W=w
$$
$\forall z\in \mathcal{Z}, \forall w\in \mathcal{W}$, where $\overset{d}{\sim}$ means "has equal distribution"

Does this imply $X\overset{d}{\sim}Y$?

I think it does by the law of total probability, but I would like to get some formal confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For any bounded measurable $g$, 
$$ \mathbb E[g(X)] = \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E[g(X) | Z, W]\right] = 
\mathbb E[\left[\mathbb E[g(Y)|Z,W]\right] = \mathbb E[g(Y)]$$

Comment: May I ask you the following: as your answer clarifies: take the random variables $X,Q, Y,Z,W$ with $Q:=g(Y,Z)$ and $Y$ independent of $Z$; then,  $X\overset{d}{\sim}Q$ does not imply $X|W \overset{d}{\sim}Q |W$ (while the converse is true). However, does  $X\overset{d}{\sim}Q$ imply $X|Z \overset{d}{\sim}Q |Z$ since $Q$ is a function of $Y,Z$ and $Z$ is independent of $Y$? Many thanks